# Write Entity Framework SQL to Debug in VB

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

In C#, you can configure Entity Framework to output SQL commands to the Debug window as they are executed.

```
Database.Log = s => { Debug.WriteLine(s); };
```

However when I try to do this in VB -

```
Database.Log = Function(s) Debug.WriteLine(s)
```

I get a compile time error, "Expression does not produce a value".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've just tried it in the conversion tool I normally use and got the following:  Private Database.Log = Sub(s)
 Debug.WriteLine(s)
End Sub  Does that work for you?

Comment: Great catch.  I was using Function when I should have been using Sub.  Write it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Private Database.Log = Sub(s)
    Debug.WriteLine(s)
End Sub
```